# GAE: No longer able to update my Gaelyk project due to appcfg losing support

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk

Recently tried to update my Gaelyk project (yes, it's old, but it works well and I still use it), but Google App Engine will no longer accept the update.  The error message returned is "Deployments using appcfg are no longer supported. See [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations%22).  The thing is, I never used appcfg to deploy my application; I used Gaelyk and Gradle.  But obviously Gaelyk must have used appcfg under the covers.

I did download the replacement Google Cloud SDK, but this new tool is not similar at all to how Gaelyk and Gradle worked.  Is there anything I can do to get Gaelyk to work anymore?  Or is Gaelyk just dead and I need to rewrite my application (like in Node.js or something instead of Groovy).

Comment: Found a Google groups discussion (https://groups.google.com/g/gaelyk/c/7hdvZCi3RBE?pli=1) from someone else who is having the same problem, so at least it's not just me.  The one thing that is clear from that Google Groups discussion is that Gaelyk is indeed dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that [Serge's answer](https://groups.google.com/g/gaelyk/c/7hdvZCi3RBE?pli=1) on the Gaelyk Groups site works; the same procedure that he figured out also worked for me.  To summarize:

1. Run **gradlew appengineRun** as run previously with Gaelyk.
2. Copy all jar files inside the **build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\lib** folder into a **\src\main\webapp\web-inf\lib** folder (for me the new lib folder did not exist previously).
3. To deploy, use the new required gcloud tool, and instead of running **gradlew appengineUpdate** (which fails now), instead run
   **gcloud app deploy appengine-web.xml** where that XML file can be found in your webapp/WEB-INF directory. I navigated to that directory to run the gcloud command, but you can use a relative path there if your working directory is elsewhere. (There are a number of optional flags associated with the gcloud app deploy command, but I didn't need any of them.)
4. Serge needed to use [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml) to convert *datastore-indexes.xml* to *index.yaml* and run **gcloud app deploy index.yaml**, however, I didn't need to do this because I had no datastores.

Answer (score 1):

This will be hard, however I will try to help you as possible. I think you may try to migrate it somehow to `app.yaml` configuration of GAE.

I am not sure what plugins are used in the project. From Gaelyk [temple project](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/download) I can see that it's using `appengine-geb` which, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/gaelyk/gradle-appengine-geb-plugin#gradle-appengine-geb-plugin),  behind the scenes, is using `gradle-appengine-plugin` (there is wrong link on this doc, but proper is bellow).

On the [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) of `gradle-appengine-plugin` I have found following.

1. There is a note:

> NOTE: All App Engine users are encouraged to transition to the [new
> gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin) for their projects.

2. And in [FAQ](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin#faq) part there is following information:

> **How do I deploy with gcloud?**
>
> If you're using gcloud to deploy your application, the newest version of app deploy > doesn't support war
> directories, you will need to provide it with an app.yaml OR you can
> use the appengineStage task to create a directory that is deployable
> in /build/staged-app
>
> `$ ./gradlew appengineStage`
>
> `$ gcloud app deploy build/staged-app/app.yaml --project [app id]`
> `--version [some version]`
>
> NOTES:
>
> - You must explicitly define all config files your want to upload
>   (cron.yaml, etc)
> - This does not work with EAR formatted projects.

I think the best option will be to migrate to new appenine plugin or if not possible try to implement is with `gcloud app deploy` command crating the config files manually (at least `app.yaml`). And for this migration I can provide you this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud).

I hope you will manage somehow...